# Solve non-linear least squares minimization

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I have a problem of the following kind $J(\mathbf{x}) = \|\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}^2\|^2 + \lambda \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}$ which has to be minimized. So it is like a Ridge regression but it contains $\mathbf{x}^2$ instead of $\mathbf{x}$ in the LS term (the penalty is still on $\mathbf{x}$ though).Can anybody help me derive its solution? I'm having some troubles when I reach deriving matrices.

I'm getting here:

$J(\mathbf{x}) = (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x})^T(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}) + \lambda \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}$

$J(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} + \lambda\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}$

$J(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} + \lambda\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}$

$J(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{y} - 2\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x} + \lambda\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}$

Minimizing means: $\frac{\delta J(\mathbf{x})}{\delta \mathbf{x}} = 0 $

And that is where I'm stuck... Anyone familiar with matrix derivations that can help me?

edit:

$\frac{\delta J(\mathbf{x})}{\delta \mathbf{x}} = 0 = -2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{y} - 2\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}+\lambda\mathbf{x}^T+\lambda\mathbf{x}^T$

$0 = -2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{y} - 2\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}+2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}+2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}+2\lambda\mathbf{x}^T$

$0 = -\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}+\lambda\mathbf{x}^T$

$\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{y}+\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}+\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}+\lambda\mathbf{x}^T$

Aaaand... I'm stuck again... And I'm not even sure my derivation is correct...

Comment: I usually use [Wikipedia: matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) or the [matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf) in such cases. In case you wanna figure it out for yourself.

Comment: Have tried a bit with your suggestion, but I'm stuck again... :(.

Comment: Is $y$ a vector? And is $x^TCx$ scalar? If so, what does $y-x^TCx$ mean?

Comment: $\mathbf{y}$ ($n$ x $1$) and $\mathbf{x}$ ($m$ x $1$) are vectors, $\mathbf{C}$ ($n$ x $m$) is a matrix. It's like in deconvolution (but with the difference that it has a nonlinear dependence)

Comment: But if $x$ is $m\times 1$ and $C$ is $n \times m$, then $x^TCx$ does not work? Anyways, I don't seem to understand the problem definition, so someone else must help out here.

Comment: Maybe I'm just wrong from the start :). Nevermind. Thanks for the help though